# Row grouping with datatables (on Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, grouping

I need to group rows in a table, according to an attribute

This is what I have:

```
Name **     First Name    **     Job       **    Country     **   Cell

Bob           Bob               Lawyer           UK               1
Brian         Brian             Consultant       France           2
Jane          Jane              Engineer         UK               3 
Nicolas       Nicolas           Doctor           France           4
```

This is what I want to have (**the attribute here is Country**):

```
Name **     First Name    **     Job       **    Country     **   Cell

Nicolas       Nicolas           Doctor           France           4
Brian         Brian             Consultant       France           2
Jane          Jane              Engineer         UK               3 
Bob           Bob               Lawyer           UK               1
```

The code I'm using to render the table is pretty classical:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>   
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
        <% Model.each do |model| %>
<td> <%=  Model.name   %> </td>
<td> <%=  Model.first_name   %> </td>
...
        <%end%>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: If you want to be able to sort and filter the table dynamically you can use a plugin like [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is sorting, not grouping. A simple `Model.order(:country).each do |model|` will do.

Comment: Perfect thanks ! But what's the difference between sorting and grouping ?

Comment: Grouping will allow aggregation functions such as min(), max(), avg(), sum() for columns. P.e. your table would have a salary column, a `.group(:country)` would allow to sum the salaries for all persons in a country.